# How do I add a download button that will download the image after making changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a photo editor and I want to add a download button that will download the image after the user makes the necessary changes. The changes are working fine but I am not able to figure out how to download the image (Please keep in mind that the filter value depends on the user and is not constant). Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed further?
(P.S. I searched all over Stack Overflow and tried to implement every solution in my code but nothing's working)

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- upload image button -->
    <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
    <p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;" id="fileBtn">UPLOAD IMAGE</label></p>
    <p><img id="img"></p>

<!-- side nav -->
<div class="sidenav">
    <label for="filter-select">FILTER AND ADJUST</label>
        <div class="slider">
            <p style="color: aliceblue;">Sepia</p>
            <input id="sepia" type="range" oninput="setSepia(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount" style="color: white;"> 0</span><br/><br>
    
            <p style="color: aliceblue;">Grayscale</p>
            <input id="Grayscale" type="range" oninput="setGs(this);" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"><span id="Amount2" style="color: white;"> 0</span><br/><br>
        </div>
    <label onclick = "RotateImg()">ROTATE</label>
    <label onclick = "flipping()">FLIP</label>
    <label onclick = "invert()">INVERT COLOURS</label>
    <label onclick = "original()">ORIGINAL</label>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function loadFile(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}

const options = {
    sepia: 0,
    grayscale: 0,
    rotation: 0,
    scale: 1,
    invertVal: 0
};

function setSepia(e){
    options.sepia = e.value;
    document.getElementById('Amount').innerHTML= e.value;
    redraw();
}

function setGs(e){
    options.grayscale = e.value;
    document.getElementById('Amount2').innerHTML= e.value;
    redraw();
}

let rotation = 0;
function RotateImg(){
    rotation += 90;
    if (rotation == 360) {
        rotation = 0;
    }
    options.rotation = rotation;
    redraw();
}

let scale = 1
function flipping() {
    scale -= 2
    if (scale <= -2) {
        scale = 1;
    }
    options.scale = scale;
    redraw();
}

let invertVal = 0
function invert() {
    invertVal += 100
    if (invertVal > 100) {
        invertVal = 0
    }
    options.invertVal = invertVal;
    redraw();
}

function original() {
    document.getElementById("img").style["webkitFilter"] ="sepia(0) grayscale(0)";
    document.querySelector("img").style.transform = "rotate(0deg) scaleX(1)";
}

function redraw() {
    document.getElementById("img").style["webkitFilter"] ="sepia(" + options.sepia + ") grayscale(" + options.grayscale + ");
    document.querySelector("img").style.transform = `rotate(${options.rotation}deg) scaleX(${options.scale})`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) to apply your edits and then use [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/toDataURL) to set up the download.

Here's a [proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/b8ec5qzx/):

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/400/400" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  <canvas width="400" height="400" />
</div>
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const image = document.querySelector('img');

image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw the image into the canvas with a sepia filter:
    ctx.filter = 'sepia(1)';
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // set up the download link
    addDownload(canvas);

})

function addDownload (canvas) {
  // create an <a>
  const a = document.createElement('a');

  // set it up to download instead of navigating
  a.setAttribute('download', 'kitten.jpg');
  a.innerHTML = "download";

  // set the href to a data url for the image
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

  // append it to the dom
  container.appendChild(a);
}
```